# Microsoft Edge loading resource very slow

Tags: html, nginx, microsoft-edge

I am a Web Developer. We have a web application which is loading very slow in Microsoft Edge. Actually, It is taking too much to get CSS minified file and javascript minified files. The web application is working once the resources loaded. It is working on other browsers like Google Chrome and Firefox.

Can anyone suggest a solution to load faster resources on Microsoft Edge?

Comment: Could you provide a repro and browser version?

Comment: Browser version is Micro soft edge 40.0. What you meant by repro?